# jQuery dataTables - expand / collapse loading ajax data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using the jquery datatables plugin and I wanted to have a collapse and expand feature as:

http://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

the data i am loding in is coming via html how should i structure the html table content so that it collapses / expands?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks for getting back to me, they have a pretty bog standard table which is fine, but they have this function in the js:

```
/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
        {
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
            var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
            sOut += '</table>';

            return sOut;
        }
```

I'm not sure how this is changing the table structure but this is being added which allows the collpased content in the table.

I want to just generate one html table with out using the script above.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that exactly what the example is doing? They have an HTML table that they are using to load the data. How is your problem different?

Comment: Hi 

I have added an update above which hopefully explains things better.

Comment: I've done complex things like that, this part of the code defines what is addedd to the table when you press the plus sign as you correctly state, why don't you want to use it?you can customize it as you want: you want data added to the table to be taken by an ajax source?

Comment: I thought it would be easier for me to return the full html of the table with expand /collapse rows via ajax, as in the expanded row I was thinking of having varying content, and not structured content as the code usd above.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
**jQuery Datatable** have inbuilt features for expand and collapse row.
use the js fiddle for example :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvgotLfz/5/